# Choose default python

Tags: python-2.7, debian, development-environment

I've just installed python2.7 in my distro debian squeeze. I'm a little confused with the way the system search for the python executable.
For example, when I type `ls -l | grep python`

I have

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          23 Feb  5 17:14 pdb2.5 -> ../lib/python2.5/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          23 Nov 23 18:29 pdb2.6 -> ../lib/python2.6/pdb.py
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root           9 Nov 23 18:29 python -> python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root     1390792 Nov 28  2010 python2.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root     2617520 Dec 27  2010 python2.6
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root        1452 Dec 27  2010 python2.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          16 Nov 23 18:49 python-config -> python2.6-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root          29 Nov 23 18:29 pyversions -> ../share/python/pyversions.py
```

The symlink shows that the python is pointed to python2.6, however when I type

```
python

The python 2.7 is the default python executable
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb  6 2013, 12:12:35) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

What I need to do to make the default python back to python 2.6?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For your question, see what does the command `ls -l $( which python )` shows. I guess it may surprise you.

If you really want to choose your own Python executable, independent on what is installed or configured on the system, I would suggest you to use [pythonbrew](https://github.com/utahta/pythonbrew).

Comment: when I type  ls -l $( which python ), I've got the result   `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff 7 Feb  6 12:13 /usr/local/bin/python -> python2` . now I just want to set back the default python to 2.6, how to do that?

Comment: I've deleted the symlink in `usr/local/bin/python` and my python2.6 is back. The reason is the `usr/local/bin` is placed before the `/usr/bin`